# Angular Material autocomplete with refresh button next to it

Tags: flexbox, angular-material, angular-material2, angular-flex-layout

I have the following angular html component:

```
<div fxLayout fxLayout.xs="row" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxLayoutGap="5px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

  <div flex class="item item-1" fxFlex="95%">
    <mat-form-field class="large-field">
      <input matInput placeholder="Full Name" aria-label="Full Name" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="FullNameCtrl">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelected($event.option.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filteredCompanyFullName | async" [value]="data">
          <span>{{ data.FullName }}</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div flex class="item item-2" fxFlex="4%">
    <button matTooltip="Refresh" mat-icon-button (click)="refresh()">
      <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

What above does is showing an auto complete drop-down plus a refresh button. I am struggling to style above html to show something like the following picture:

[image]

However it looks like the following which is not the desired output:

[image]

What should I change to achieve the first image? I want the input field to take 95% width of the row and a small refresh button right next to it aligned to the right.

Comment: Change to `fxLayout.xs="row"` on `container`

Comment: Changed it but that doesn't do it.

Comment: Then we need a working code snippet, so we can see what goes wrong.

Comment: That is the complete html code for the component and there is no CSS behind the component itself. The component itself doesn't do that much either. For the sake of easiness you just consider that autocomplete as a simple input box. I just want to know how I align them in one single row similar to the image. Clearly I am missing something very tiny.

Comment: How about dropping the `.xs`, or add `fxLayout="row"` ... not using angular-flex that much, but just realized the `.xs` might work similar to Bootstrap, where `.xs` is for smaller screens.

Comment: made your suggested change but still looking the same.

Comment: Then all I do now is guessing. And you have classes like `container`, `item` etc., so what does they look like? ... To really provide a solution, it is necessary with a working code snippet reproducing the issue, with all resources linked, etc.

Comment: @LGSon, I tried to follow https://alligator.io/angular/flex-layout/ and also removed the container class. The code I posted is the complete code and there is nothing more to post.

Comment: I believe that, still, I can't run that code and see what's going on since I don't have an angular environment installed. If you take the code in this fiddle, does it align them side-by-side: http://jsfiddle.net/cc81k366/

Comment: Also, make sure you've imported the dependency `@angular/flex-layout`

Comment: Can't you use the `matPrefix` property on the button?

Comment: At https://codesandbox.io/ you can set up and test Angular apps. Please do and provide us a link to it, and we'll get a better chance to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Please use like below and it should work,

```
<div fxLayout fxLayout.xs="row" fxLayoutAlign="left" fxLayoutGap="5px" fxLayoutGap.xs="0">

  <div flex class="item item-1" fxFlex="100%">
    <mat-form-field class="large-field">
      <input matInput placeholder="Full Name" aria-label="Full Name" [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="FullNameCtrl">
      <button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button>
        <mat-icon>refresh</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelected($event.option.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let data of filteredCompanyFullName | async" [value]="data">
          <span>{{ data.FullName }}</span>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**